# LocalDB .mdf file not attached automatically with AttachDbFileName in connection string

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string, sql-server-2014, localdb

I'm expecting this behavior because of [this MSDN article about the AttachDbFileName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#attachdbfilename)

> The first time you connect to a database by using this option in the
>   connection string, the SQL Server Express or LocalDB instance attaches
>   the database, and it stays attached. When you want to connect to the
>   same database in the future you could use Initial Catalog without
>   AttachDbFileName if you prefer.

I have a connection string that is used by Entity Framework:

```
<add name="DatabaseContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=|DatabaseName|\DatabaseName.mdf" />
```

This works fine after I open the database in SQL Management Studio feeding it the AttachDbFileName value with the absolute path as an additional prameter.

But if I don't attached it with SQL Management Studio first then I'm getting the following error when trying to run EF migrations on the database:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot create file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\DatabaseName.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__19(DbConnection conn)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
```

This looks as if it doesn't attach the database automatically for some reason and then tries to create it as if the file didn't exist.

Is there an additional connection string option or LocalDB configuration that can fix this so that the database is attached automatically on the first conneciton?

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the Web.Config may help to understand what happened here.  The LocalDB is a database that is meant to serve as a file.   If you have an actual database you could change the connection string.  Either way, check the version of your localdb (example 2019 would be version 15 of sql server and version 13 of the localdb).   If the one in the connection string (web.config) points to a different location, it is a task for editing the connection string.

```
https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is trivial: the .mdf and .ldf files were created in a newer version of SQL server so the older version was not attaching them as if they didn't exist.